# Js in php command line

Tags: php

How can I use  javascript in php command line. When I write

```
<script>documen.Write("Hello World.");</script>
```

it's printing same things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on `document.write()`, although that won't matter anyway as javascript can only execute in a browser a javascript shell.

Also, it appears you are not the first person to ask this question:

[execute js function by php command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826953/execute-js-function-by-php-command-line)